# Google Classroom api to get classwork material

Tags: google-classroom

I am trying to get Classwork information from Google Classroom using Classroom api. But it only pulls the document details. But the material details are not showing.

I am using PHP code to get the details

```
    $assignmentResults = $service->courses_courseWork->listCoursesCourseWork($courseId);
  //print_r($assignmentResults); exit;
    if(count($assignmentResults->getCourseWork())>0):
        foreach ($assignmentResults->getCourseWork() as $assignment) {
            //print("<pre>".print_r($assignment,true)."</pre>");exit;
            $arrAssignment[$i]['id'] = $assignment->id;
            $arrAssignment[$i]['title'] = $assignment->title;
            $arrAssignment[$i]['description'] = $assignment->description; 
            $arrAssignment[$i]['materials'] = $this->getMaterials($assignment->materials);
            $arrAssignment[$i]['assignment'] = $this->assignment($assignment->assignment);
            $i++;
        }
    endif;
```

See the attached images. The expected results are highlighted on the images.

[image: Material][image]